# SAPUI5 doesn't handle onclick event in disabled HTML element

Tags: javascript, onclick, sapui5

I'm developing a SAPUI5 application. And in the page, the user has to select an item from *select_A* before he/she selects from *select_B*. Until he/she selects from *select_A*, the *select_B* box is disabled.

What I would like to have is: even when the *select_B* box is **disabled**, and the user tries to click it before selecting from *select_A*, the *select_A* box should become red.

I tried using `onclick` event, but, when the box is disabled, it doesn't do anything.

Only as a test, I made this:

```js
oSelectTamanho = new sap.m.Select();
oSelectTamanho.onclick = function() {
  console.log("click");
}
```

As I mentioned, it only outputs the "click" when the box is enabled, and I would need this when the box is disabled.

Do you have any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please consider accepting https://stackoverflow.com/a/66222770/5846045 instead. The current accepted answer encourages working with rendered HTMLElement directly which should be avoided in UI5.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you see, [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled) elements do not produce [`events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event). Using an overlay element is one possible solution. Example using an overlay div.

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
#overlay {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
#cars:disabled + #overlay {
    display:block;
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="button">Enable</button>
<div id="wrapper">
    <select id="cars" disabled>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var button = document.getElementById('button'),
    cars = document.getElementById('cars'),
    overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    cars.disabled = !cars.disabled;
    if (cars.disabled) {
        button.textContent = 'Enable';
    } else {
        button.textContent = 'Disable';
    }
}, true);

cars.addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.value);
}, true);

overlay.addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert('Disabled');
}, true);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/AmLa7/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using a single SAPUI5 framework API ([`oElement.addEventDelegate`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.Element#methods/addEventDelegate)): https://jsbin.com/zuramop/edit?js,output.

> ```js
> myDisabledControl.addEventDelegate({
>   onclick:/*or ontap: */() => alert("Select that other item first!"),
> });
> ```
>
> <sup>(See the [API reference of `sap/ui/events/ControlEvents.events`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/module:sap/ui/events/ControlEvents) for other available events.)</sup>

Please do **not** manipulate the HTML element of UI5 controls directly!