# Disable button if radio is unchecked. Enable when checked

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling, radio-button

I can't seem to get my button to re-enable after it's been disabled. Currently, if nothing is checked and I mouseover it, the button disables. It stays enabled if I have something checked, but if I first hover over then button, with nothing checked, I can't get it to re-enable if I check something.

Here's My JS:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var letsCookButton = document.querySelector('#letsCook');

letsCookButton.addEventListener('mouseover', checkIfChecked);

function checkIfChecked() {
  letsCookButton.disabled = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].checked) {
      letsCookButton.disabled = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
div class="mainBox" id="box-one">
          <p id="left-box-title">What are you looking for?<span>*</span></p>
          <ul>
            <li><input type="radio" name="food" id="side-food"> Side</li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="food" id="main-food"> Main Dish</li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="food" id="dessert-food"> Dessert</li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="food" id="entire-meal"> Entire Meal</li>
          </ul>
          <button id="letsCook">LET'S COOK!</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to slightly rethink how you want the UX of your app to work, because [disabled elements do not produce events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24824133/3011431).

Since at least one radio button will remain checked after the first click, I would suggest disabling the button from the start and then enabling it on a radio click event.

```html
<div class="mainBox" id="box-one">
  <p id="left-box-title">What are you looking for?<span>*</span></p>
  <ul id="radio-group">
    <li><input type="radio" name="food" id="side-food"> Side</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="food" id="main-food"> Main Dish</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="food" id="dessert-food"> Dessert</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="food" id="entire-meal"> Entire Meal</li>
  </ul>
  <button id="letsCook" disabled>LET'S COOK!</button>
</div>
```

```js
var inputGroup = document.querySelector('#radio-group');
var letsCookButton = document.querySelector('#letsCook');

inputGroup.addEventListener('click', function () {
    letsCookButton.removeAttribute('disabled')
});
```

Working example in JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ollie1700/wxn9f63p/4/